# Exploding the group by cel in individual cases

Tags: python, sql, group-by

I am trying to convert the following table (fictitious):

| Person | year | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 2019 | 100 |
| Klaas | 2020 | 100 |
| John | 2019 | 120 |
| John | 2020 | 120 |
| Klaas | 2020 | 150 |
| Klaas | 2020 | 150 |
| John | 2020 | 150 |

into:

| Person | year | price | price | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tom | 2019 | 100 | NaN | NaN |
| Klaas | 2020 | 100 | 150 | 150 |
| John | 2019 | 120 | NaN | NaN |
| John | 2020 | 120 | 150 | NaN |

In fact, I group the data by person and year. Next, I desire to 'explode' the group by column. I work in azure data bricks resulting that both SQL and python works for me. I was thinking maybe I could add a extra cell to the row if Person==Person & year==year

Could someone help me?
Btw. Does someone have the correct name for this problem.

Kind regards.

Comment: Oof.. don't do it. Turning rows into columns makes life hard work

Comment: Thanks for your question,  but the different price columns represent the number of occurrences in that years. For example, the price 120 occurred once in 2019 (john). Twice the price was found in 2020 (120,150)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select person, year,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then price end) as price_1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then price end) as price_2,
       max(case when seqnum = 3 then price end) as price_3
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by person, year order by price) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by person, year;
```